# how to list glassfish instances?

Tags: glassfish, freebsd, java, glassfish-4.1

I have a glassfish domain running, but I cannot get the PID of the associated java process, is this broken or am I doing something wrong?  I have FreeBSD 10.1, OpenJDK 1.7.0, and Glassfish 4.1.

```
$ asadmin list-domains -l
DOMAIN   ADMIN_HOST  ADMIN_PORT  RUNNING  RESTART_REQUIRED
domain1  127.0.0.1   4848        true     false
Command list-domains executed successfully.
$ asadmin list-instances -l
Nothing to list.
Command list-instances executed successfully.
```

I can do `jps -v`, but with that I am not 100% sure the listed PID is my glassfish server...

```
$ jps -v
62737 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/local/openjdk7 -Xms8m
```

**EDIT:**

Ok. the `jps` command is definitely not what I want - that is just showing itself.  Also I tried

```
$ asadmin list-instances -l domain1
remote failure: The target, domain1, is not an instance, cluster, domain, node or config.
Command list-instances failed.
```

and

```
$ asadmin list-instances -l 127.0.0.1
remote failure: The target, 127.0.0.1, is not an instance, cluster, domain, node or config.
Command list-instances failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this issue from the Glassfish JIRA Server.

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12744

Comment: I saw that, I did not understand it -- what is DAS?

Comment: Oops it was [this - 12684](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12684) I saw...  I also saw your item and it looked like it was put in 3.1 so I should have it in 4.1.